# How can I create a model with compound foreign key?

Tags: python, django-models, postgis, geodjango, compound-key

anybody knows on how to create a model with compound foreign key to another model.

e.g.

UserInfo: **userId**, **password**, key, ...

GeoInfo: id, **userId**, **password**, storeName, ...

In the above sample models. Want to link GeoInfo to UserInfo using two fields (**userId, password**).

note:I know how to link two models with one foreign key.

Any guidance is appreciated.

**UPDATES1**
I found this post -> [Django or similar for composite primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624257/django-or-similar-for-composite-primary-keys)

Unfortunately, the accepted answer there is not applicable in my case due to requirement (client's specifications) to have exist the two fields(**UserInfo.userId, UserInfo.password**) in GeoInfo.

**UPDATES2**
so it seems, django doesn't support compound foreign keys. any workaround guys?

Comment: Please do not put tags in the title.

Answer (score 0):

What's keeping you from having two ForeignKey field referencing Model A?

e.g.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name="primary_authors")
    co_author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name ="co_authors")
```

make sure to use 'related_name' to prevent conflicts. If this doesn't answer your question, providing an example of what you're trying to do would help...

Comment: I can't understand where is `primary_authors` and `co_authors`? I will update my post to have actual name.

Comment: Two Foreign Keys is a different thing than a compound Foreign Key.

Comment: >What's keeping you from having two ForeignKey field -> it requires by the client for some reason.