# Using Composite Primary keys with Django

Tags: python, django, composite-primary-key

I am using Django 1.6, and i want to use composite primary keys. I know that its not directly supported by Djnago. But is there any alternative or packages to implement that. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django or similar for composite primary keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624257/django-or-similar-for-composite-primary-keys)

Comment: i already saw that...but i don't want any auto incremented key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composite primary key in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712848/composite-primary-key-in-django)

Comment: i've implemented basic support for virtual Composite Keys. No database modifications are required stackoverflow.com/a/65404017/46548

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Django with [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) instead of the native ORM for models where you need composite primary keys.

You will not be able to use the admin app with SQLAlchemy models without a surrogate key (this is probably the case with most of the Django ecosystem). You will also need a ModelForm replacement like [WTForms](http://wtforms-alchemy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

If you need composite primary keys, take a look at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) instead, You will be able to leverage most of your Django skills. It is very well documented and has a sizeable ecosystem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...but the requirement is to use PostgreSql and Django.

Comment: Django does not support SQLAlchemy natively but it can coexists seamlessly with Djangos ORM. I have used it in projects where I have to interface to a legacy database having composite primary keys.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would really appreciate an example for defining the composite primary keys using SQlAchemy with coexistance of Django model, as i have not used SQlAchemy ever. Thanks again.

Comment: Hii...i am waiting for your help. If you have some time please give me an example of what i mentioned above. It would be of great help. Thanks.